# HttpGet for with BBC news rss feed

Tags: java, android, rss

I wish to load the web page from BBC rss feed with the HttpGet function in my android app.  When I get the link from rss feed, and I use

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
try{
   String response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
   textView.setText(response_str);
   }
```

For the RSS feed from NY times, I can get the context in their webpage, which means this function at least work for some situation. However, in the BBC new's cases, I only get a webpage like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
"http:///www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">

<html xmlns= "http:///www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocal.org/schema." xml:lang="en-GB">
```

I am wondering are there any redirect situation I needs to handle or something? Otherwise it will be strange if this code works for some webpage while not work for others.

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what URL you are using, but the following code works for me:

```
final String feedURLStr = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml?edition=uk#";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet method = new HttpGet(feedURLStr);
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
final String responseStr = client.execute(method, handler);
System.out.println(responseStr);
```

Verify that you are using a valid feed URL (partial list can currently be viewed [here](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/help/rss/default.stm)).

Comment: Thanks, actually my Original code works well, I just forget to scroll down the content. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial is very helpful for you to read rss feed please have a look here.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/